# How to add SQLCE and SQLITE to C#?

Tags: c#, sqlite, sql-server-ce

i need your help.
I need to create a windows forms application and add 2 databases to it, sqlite and sql-ce, with testing purposes.can you give me some tutorials or documentation to learn how to add that db-s to my project?.
I tried to find with google, but the results are some kind of confusing, that's why i'm asking here.thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you give some C# sample code of your project? That would help us to identify which kind of data access suits best. And a bit more information of what you intend to do with it would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for SQL-Ce you to need first to download SQL Compact (try [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17876) )
and then add:

```
System.Data.SqlServerCe;
```

to your Project.

The syntax of the coding follows the same logic with `System.Data.SqlClient;` dll expect you need to add the `ce` prefix, e.g:

```
ceConn = new SqlCeConnection(CONNECTIONSTRING);
```

For SQLlite see [this](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/157830-using-sqlite-with-c#/#/)

Comment: one more question, i've installed, downloaded the dll's, created the references...now what if i want to create my db's locally, outside visual studio and then add them to the project. how can i do that?

Comment: Opee Server Explorer and select "Add Database"..From the available RDBMS choose SQL CE database

Comment: I am not user you can add sqlite to VS